# Capture current JSF page content

Tags: session, pdf, jsf

I want to capture the current page and send it to an application that converts it to pdf.

This is what I am using:

```
FacesContext facesContext=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();


       HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)
facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
       HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
//        RequestPrinter.debugString();
       response.reset();
    // download a pdf file
       response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+new Date().toString()+".pdf");
         prince.setVerbose(true);
        prince.setLog(logFile);

            try{


                //getPath() to the page the user is currently on
                URL pagePath=new URL(this.getPath());
                URLConnection urlConnection = pagePath.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                int length = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                //Lets use inputStream
                BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                response.setContentLength(length);
                //this.getPageUsingJSoup().data().getBytes();
                //call prince and pass params for inputstream  outputStream

                prince.convert(bis,response.getOutputStream());
                urlConnection.getInputStream().close();

            }catch(MalformedURLException mu){

                mu.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

   facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Since the website requires authentication, the pdf generated is the loging error page.

Is there a way to capture the page's content that uses the current user's session?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just request the page in the same HTTP session as the current request. If your webapp supports URL rewriting (as by default), then just append session ID as `jsessionid` path fragment:

```
String sessionId = ((HttpSession) externalContext.getSession()).getId();
InputStream input = new URL("http://localhost:8080/context/page.jsf;jsessionid=" + sessionId).openStream();
// ...
```

Or if your webapp doesn't accept URL rewriting, but accepts cookies only, then set it as a request cookie the usual way:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost:8080/context/page.jsf").openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionId);
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
// ...
```

Note that I removed `setDoOutput()` since you don't seem to be interested in performing a POST request.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, our webapp supports URL rewriting. I tried you first suggestion but I still get the error login page. The webapp uses  Seam Authentication and prince (the application I am using to print the pdf) is an installation on my windows machine. Is there a way to get past the login or bind that new urlconnection to the authenticated session. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Seam Authentication, so I can't go in the details, but it's theoretically quite possible that it requires an additional request cookie. I'd monitor the HTTP traffic between your regular webbrowser (press F12 in Chrome/IE10/Firebug and check "Net"/"Network" section) and the webserver to see if there aren't additional cookies in the request headers. If so, then you should simulate the very same cookies in your programmatic request.

Comment: ,on the browser (after clearing cache and login in again), I only have a jsessionid cookie and the session storage is empty. In the tomcat manager, under Active HttpSessions informations, the active sessions have the column names : Session Id,Guessed Locale, Guessed User name, Creation Time,Last Accessed Time, Used Time ,Inactive Time and TTL.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to capture the page's content using the current user's session, but I can suggest another way to do it - you could move the pdf conversion logic inside a Selenium test-case and use the test-case to navigate and login to the page requiring authentication. After the automated tc has logged in, you could call your pdf conversion logic...?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course there is. You are sending this content, so you have it. You should store the Content Object. If you dont have it, inspect your byte streams. The content should be there ;)

Comment: Thanks @Evgheni and Stimpson Cat. I prefer capturing the contents of the page. Stimpson, could you give me an idea of how I can access the content.The printPDF() method is in a different managed bean from the managed bean used to render the page.

Comment: I am sorry. I do not have that much experience with EJB. Maybe i am wrong, i oversaw that you are working with this crappy thing. I am not sure, maybe the managed Bean is protected by the container? The more i think about it, the more i am lucky that i never used EJB ;)

Answer (score 0):

There of couple of websites which allow you to convert the entire page to pdf and save it as .pdf file. Try out the site http://pdfcrowd.com/ Hope this helps you.